# How to change an NSBox location (or position?) programmatically in objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, attributes, location

I am learning objective c and am making some small programs. For my current project i am taking a `NSBox` and changing it's location based on a random number. How do I change the box's location? With C# it was a simple `box.location = anotherLocation` but I can't figure out how to do this in Objective-C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the location of the NSBox, you have to use the `setFrame` method:

```
NSRect frame = [box frame];
frame.origin = NSMakePoint(newX, newY);
[box setFrame:frame];
```

Comment: You can just do `[box setFrameOrigin:NSMakePoint(newX, newY)]`. No need for an intermediate NSRect.